# Unable to modify active record inside of net/http callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, net-http

I'm unable to set an attribute in the callback of a Net::HTTP GET request.

Why is this happening?

```
def validate(params)

... net http setup ...
res = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI(path))
        print res.body
        print res.code << prints 200
        if res.code == 404
            puts "404"
        elsif res.code == 200
            user.validated = Time.now
            user.save
            valid = Time.now
            puts "user.validated: #{user.validated}" << this does not 
        end
 puts user.validated # prints nil
```

Comment: Are you sure its `prints 200`?

Comment: Yes, I tested. It prints 200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the result of `res.code` is a string ("200" or "404"), not a number.

your code should be:

```
....
if res.code == "404"
   puts "404"
elsif res.code == "200"
....
```